# Errors with traversal method of generic stack

Tags: java, generics, stack

I have a problem with the following method: `public void traverseGStack()` the line with print is giving me an error for some reason. In class we did it like I wrote it but I think the problem might be with `E obj = (E) temp.obj` is there another way to store GNode object into generic? Thank you and if I am unclear tell me to rephrase

CODE OF GSTACK

```
import linearnode.*;
import dataobjects.*;
public class GStack <E>
{
    GNode top;
    //-----------constructors ---------
    public GStack()
    {
        top = null; //--empty stack----
    }
    //-----methods -------
    public void push (E newObj)
    {
        GNode temp = new GNode (newObj);
        if(top != null){
            temp= temp.next;
            top = temp;
        }
    }

    public E pop ()
    {
        if(top != null){
            E temp = (E)top;
            top = top.next;
            return temp;
        }
        else return null;
    }

    //--utility methods --
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        if(top == null) 
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void traverseGStack(){ //to observe contents of the GStack
        if(top != null){
            GNode temp = top;
            while (temp != null){
                **E obj =  (E)temp.obj;** // this might be wrong
                System.out.println(obj.getData()); //as implemetned BUT in normal stack use : temp.obj.getObj()               
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNode also needs generics: A `GStack<E>` contains one `GNode<E>` named `top`, which has a field named `obj`, of type `E`.

> `E temp = (E)top;`

This is wrong. `top` is a `GNode`, not an `E`.

> `**E obj =  (E)temp.obj;** // this might be wrong`

No, that's fine - though if your GNode class is also genericsed, you will not need the cast to E anymore, which is nice.

Comment: Not in the pasted code it isn't. `GNode top;` - that'd have to be `GNode<E> top;`.